Why OOM killer doesn't catch the obvious misbehaving process?
On a CentOS 7 (with a 3.10 kernel) server I was surprised to find out that mysqld process was "oom killed". The reason was obvious, I sometimes run a very memory hungry process (WebTorrent), that sometimes grow into an abomination (looks like a memory leak). It's fine by me, as long as it gets killed when that happens. On another system (Debian 11), this was the actual behavior, but here on the older CentOS 7, other processes are killed, wand I don't understand why not the most obvious one?
From logs (only selected lines):
Apr 20 09:12:57 vps001 kernel: mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Apr 20 09:12:58 vps001 kernel: Out of memory (oom_kill_allocating_task): Kill process 996 (mysqld) score 0 or sacrifice child
Apr 20 09:12:58 vps001 kernel: Killed process 918 (mysqld), UID 27, total-vm:2184052kB, anon-rss:18492kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
--
Apr 20 09:26:40 vps001 kernel: in:imjournal invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Apr 20 09:26:40 vps001 kernel: Out of memory (oom_kill_allocating_task): Kill process 663 (in:imjournal) score 0 or sacrifice child
Apr 20 09:26:40 vps001 kernel: Killed process 653 (rsyslogd), UID 0, total-vm:308640kB, anon-rss:340kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:156kB
--
Apr 20 09:26:40 vps001 kernel: tmux invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Apr 20 09:26:41 vps001 kernel: Out of memory (oom_kill_allocating_task): Kill process 23040 (tmux) score 0 or sacrifice child
Apr 20 09:26:41 vps001 kernel: Killed process 23041 (bash), UID 0, total-vm:115680kB, anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB
--
Apr 20 09:26:41 vps001 kernel: node invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x200da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Apr 20 09:26:41 vps001 kernel: Out of memory (oom_kill_allocating_task): Kill process 23241 (node) score 0 or sacrifice child
Apr 20 09:26:41 vps001 kernel: Killed process 23239 (WebTorrent), UID 1000, total-vm:14750096kB, anon-rss:1618448kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

3 processes were killed before the good one, for reasons I can't grasp.
Things I would expect:

The process which consumes the most memory is killed
A process with UID 0 is not killed before other UID
UID 27 is more "important" as UID 1000

I would like to better understand the OOM behavior and especially why all my assomptions were wrong about it.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-does-the-oom-killer-decide-which-process-to-kill-first

I sometimes run a very memory hungry process (WebTorrent), that sometimes grow into an abomination (looks like a memory leak). It's fine by me my guess would be the system hadn't calculated the oom score for the offending process yet. And, there isn't much criteria that you are looking for.

It seems that the system hasn't calculated any score, which are all "0". Is the score calculation something than can be enabled/disabled?

OK, found it.
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 0 to scan processes (the default behavior I want)
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 1 to kill the process that ask for memory

Reading the kernel source code and now I see, it's obvious:
oom_kill_allocating_task means that no scan is performed and the asking process is killed.
This is not the default behaviour and I've had a sysctl config somewhere setting it:
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 1

So I must have set it a long time ago without understanding the consequences.
Thanks for your comments.
